# makefile problem

Tags: gcc, makefile

I can not create executable code by using a makefile. How can I generate the executable code. I wrote this lines into my makefile and in the terminal I wrote make but I can not do it. Please help me.

```
myprog : myprog.o mylibrary.o
    gcc myprog.o mylibrary.o -o myprog

myprog.o : myprog.c mylibrary.h
    gcc -c myprog.c mylibrary.h -o myprog.o

mylibrary.o : mylibrary.c mylibrary.h
    gcc -c mylibrary.c -o mylibrary.o
```

I take lost separator error. How can I fix this?

Comment: what's the output when you run `make`?

Comment: The whitespace before each `gcc ...` is actually a TAB, right?

Comment: yes I press tab button.Besides the output is "There is no rule to compile myprog.c,'myprog.o' needs this."

Comment: Is `myprog.c` there, in that directory?

Comment: You don't list the headers on the compile lines; at least, not usually.  The compilers tend to dislike it.  Also note that if you are not careful, `vim` will expand tabs into spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `-o` after the other calls to gcc. Also, be sure you typed `\t` (tab key) in the indentation (not white spaces, but a real tab char). Be sure your text editor is not configured to use white spaces instead of tabs if this is the case.

```
myprog : myprog.o mylibrary.o
    gcc myprog.o mylibrary.o -o myprog

myprog.o : myprog.c mylibrary.h
    gcc -c myprog.c mylibrary.h -o myprog.o

mylibrary.o : mylibrary.c mylibrary.h
    gcc -c mylibrary.c -o mylibrary.o
```

Please, when writing a question, never forget to tell the error messages you get. This helps identifying the problem and give an accurate answer.

I hope this helps you. Take care,
Beco

Comment: I try your code Dr Beco,but at this time I took "lost separator" error.

Comment: @virtue Was not ` *** missing separator.  Stop. ` ? If that is happening, you probably should check if your editor allows you to insert TAB to indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
myprog : myprog.o mylibrary.o
        gcc myprog.o mylibrary.o -o myprog

myprog.o :
        gcc -c myprog.c

mylibrary.o :
        gcc -c mylibrary.c
```